# How to get iti__dial-code in intl-tel-input?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want just to get only country code with plus in html input, this intl-tel-input now working, that showing specific country code number example. I don`t want this , what i need is just to show automatically iti__dial-code (country code) .

How can i solve this issue ?

```
var input = document.querySelector("#phone");
intlTelInput(input, {
customPlaceholder: function(selectedCountryPlaceholder, selectedCountryData) {
return "(201) 555-0123" ;
  },
});
window.intlTelInput(input, {
  initialCountry:"auto",  
  geoIpLookup: function(success, failure){
    $.get("https://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
        var countryCode = ('+' && resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
        success(countryCode);
    });
  },
  dropdownContainer: document.body,
  utilsScript: "Project A_files/utils.js",
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get instance of input and then get it's country data.

```
var iti = window.intlTelInputGlobals.getInstance(input);
var countryData = iti.getSelectedCountryData();
```

Country data will return something like:

```
{
 name: "Afghanistan (‫افغانستان‬‎)",
 iso2: "af",
 dialCode: "93"
}
```

Get the dialcode by:

```
var dialCode = countryData["dialCode"];
```

Refered from the official documentation of the library at https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input